# Allow Authentication server access to Resource server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I'm working with the Spring **OAuth2** sparklr and toner examples. I've broken up sparklr into two applications to separate the **Resource** server and **Authentication** server. They're both running on **Spring Boot** and **Java Config**.

The Resource server (API) has a /account resource I would like to expose to the Authentication server (MVC) so that the Auth server can create accounts, but of course the resource is protected.

How can I grant the Authentication server access to the /account on the Resource server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your /account resource is an oauth protected resource then your auth server is now a client. I don't see any in principle problem with that (copy the client side config from tonr and use an `OAuth2RestTemplate` like it was a vanilla `RestTemplate`). You haven't really provided enough information to know what kind of client and grant type should be used (maybe client_credentials?).

Comment: Makes sense. client_credentials should work fine for now. Thanks.